# Is it possible to use Newtonsoft.Json when using HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(something)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

Let's say I want to add a typed `HttpClient` like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient<ISomeService, SomeService>(c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(someUrl);
});
```

Is it possible to force it to use `Newtonsoft.Json` for serialization when sending requests? Preferably in a similar fashion how it can be added for controllers:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

So that when I use `HttpClient` instance like that: `await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(testDto)`, `Newtonsoft.Json` serializer is used instead of the built-in one.

**EDIT: Just noticed that `PostAsJsonAsync(...)` and `GetFromJsonAsync(...)` I am using are extension methods defined in `System.Net.Http.Json`, which basically renders this whole question invalid.**

Comment: Yeah, reading the title my first thought was "what in the world is a typed `HttpClient`"? What you're doing is adding a wrapper that's typed, the actual `HttpClient` instance is still just a plain one -- and by the way, shared with all the other "typed `HttpClient`" mappings.

Comment: It's something described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#how-to-use-typed-clients-with-ihttpclientfactory.

Comment: Question is confusing, but what he's basically asking is in `HttpClientExtensions` namespace, how to you set up the default serializer for `PostAsJsonAsync` and `ReadAsAsync` methods.

Comment: @Slowacki, it's exactly what I said, one shared `HttpClient`, and a whole bunch of mappings per type to different delegates. There's no such thing as a "typed `HttpClient`".

Comment: @Andy Yep that's what this is mostly about :) Sorry, I'll try to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: @Blindy Yes, that is what you described. What I'm saying is, the 'Typed Client' term comes from the Microsoft documentation and that's why I use it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `Newtonsoft.Json`, use the extension methods on the `System.Net.Http.HttpClientExtensions` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh944845(v=vs.118)).

If you want to use the new `System.Text.Json`, use extension methods on the `System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions).

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that and my controllers seem to make use of e.g. `JsonProperty` that's added to some properties on my DTOs. However, I've noticed that when using `await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(testDto)` the built-in serializer (`System.Net.Http.Json`) is being used instead. Hence the question.

Comment: @Slowacki -- If you look at the source code, it looks like it's still hard-coded to `Newtonsoft.Json`... I don't believe there is a way to change this, at least i have never seen a way.

Comment: @Slowacki -- For reference: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/JsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs#L119  I am going to update my answer, because now it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Well, that's a shame, but not completely unexpected :( I just wish in .Net 5 the built-in serializer is actually finished, so that I can finally ditch `Newtonsoft.Json`...

Comment: Ah yes, I just noticed, that `PostAsJsonAsync` is actually an extension that comes directly from `System.Net.Http.Json`, so that might make some sense why any other serializer cannot be specified :D

Comment: @Slowacki -- i updated my answer. You can write your own extensions that use whatever serializer you want. That's the beauty of extensions.

Comment: Yes, just noticed that it's just an extension from `System.Net.Http.Json`. My bad!

Comment: Can you just change your answer to say that it's going to use `System.Net.Http.Json` because that's where the extension method is coming from and I can write my own extensions for posting with `Newtonsoft.Json`. Then I'll be able to accept it :)

Comment: @Slowacki -- whew -- i knew we'd get there sooner or later :)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this answer. I understand the namespaces but having installed HttpClientExtensions from nuget and sitting here with the wrong serializer, I see no solution here. The 1st namespace mentioned doesn't exist in the nuget library I downloaded so what nuget/version is required to get the JSON serializing here?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. `System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions` isn't a namespace, it's a class that is hardcoded to use Newtonsoft, so it isn't using `System.Text.Json`.